# Connecting to LDAPS with WAMP Server

Tags: php, ssl, ldap

What is required to get a WAMP Server to connect as a client to an LDAPS (LDAP over SSL) server? Specifically, where do LDAPS client certificates go on a WAMP Server, and what other elements need to be configured?

NOTE: The client program will be connecting via PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the Windows part of the WAMP stack. The tricky part is having the correct [PHP libraries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php) installed to talk to LDAP, and configuring those libraries.

Create yourself a [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) script and check your LDAP support and configuration. Once the libraries are squared away, create an ldap.conf and place it in the appropriate location (ie. where PHP thinks it goes). Be sure to add directives that point to your certificate files. If your LDAPS server is, in fact, Active Directory, be prepared for some extremely picky SSL requirements.